# Shim only works in non-Secure Boot mode

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, refind, secure-boot

I'm trying to get my dual boot (Arch+Win10) to work with Secure Boot.
I followed the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#shim), with the following steps.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi
sudo cp /usr/share/shim-signed/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
sudo cp /usr/share/shim-signed/mmx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout MOK.key -new -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -subj "/CN=MOK_LENOVO_MASSIMO/" -out MOK.crt
sudo openssl x509 -outform DER -in MOK.crt -out MOK.cer
sudo openssl x509 -outform DER -in MOK.crt -out MOK.cer
sudo sbsign --key MOK.key --cert MOK.crt --output /boot/vmlinuz-linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux
sudo sbsign --key MOK.key --cert MOK.crt --output /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
sudo cp MOK.cer /boot/efi/EFI/
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

As I enabled Secure Boot the system booted direclty into windows (which is after the new "shim" bootx64.efi, still called "rEFInd Boot Manager", in the boot order).

Disabling SB got me to a working refind again, which, I guess, means that shim is properly configured, but the system does not reckognize its signed key? The Wiki and the [refind site](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#initial_shim) tell me I should be prompted with MOK tool, since Shim, signed with Microsoft key, can't chainload (a not yet signed) refind.

**How do I make shim chainload MokManager?**

EDIT: I had a look at [the Shim source code](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/master/shim.c) and indeed it seems that, if there were errors, shim would print them happily (which doesn't happen). It just silently boot windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either create your MOK *and* sign the bootloader with it *or* get a complementary shim+bootloader pair (as in "bootloader signed with the certificate that shim was compiled with") -- see also the excellent Rod's books on the topic ([Dealing with Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#using_signed), [Controlling Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html)) as well as my [UEFI SecureBoot mini-HOWTO](https://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) if you're interested in helping Arch getting their shim signed by UEFI CA (== MSFT).

Getting a Linux distro that actually went through that pain for you might be way easier though (I know Fedora, SUSE, Ubuntu, [ALT](https://en.altlinux.org/rescue) and ROSA as of today although there might be more).

PS: the exact (but [useless](https://nargaque.com/2014/03/02/mathematicians-answer/)) answer is that your shim works as intended already...

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't get why this should be the correct configuration... If shim works but doesn't prompt me with MOK tool, how could I ever sign the bootloader with it's key?
Unfortunately the Arch mods don't want to follow the "official EFI signature" way (also because it follows the Rolling Release model, I guess?), but I like this distro much more than the others

Comment: It's not related to "rolling release" at all (as long as there's at least one shim-signed already), and MOK doesn't _sign_ anything but can rather tell firmware that it should accept a _particular binary_ by its hash (because that's what the machine owner wants explicitly).